# Python multiple click.options - got unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-click

While using python click, I am not being able to pass the options to one of the method. Please consider following code.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--config', default='default.cfg', help = 'comfiguration file')
@click.option('--port', default=9093)
def foo(config_name, port):
    print('Function has been successfully called..!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config
```

and the stacktrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    foo()
  File "/home/sagar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sagar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/sagar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/sagar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
```

I do not understand why this is so. I read few similar questions regarding `argument`, that one cannot use `help` option, but in this case I think I am not doing anything that is not supported.

But the funny thing is: if I remove the `--config` option, (and of course the parameter from the function), then it works perfectly. I am sure one can use multiple options, I tried using `type=string`, but it also does not help.

Comment: You can rename arguments if needed,see e.g. http://click.pocoo.org/5/parameters/#parameter-names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named the option `--config`, so click is trying to pass an argument named `config` to `foo`, but there's no `config` in `foo`'s signature.  Presumably, you want to write `def foo(config, port):` instead of `def foo(config_name, port):`.

Comment: doh! thanks. I made the same mistake